# My computer is acting weird after I upgraded the processor and ram

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, cpu

I built a desktop computer on budget and the specs were

- Msi 760gm- p23 Motherboard
- Amd Sempron 145
- LOGISYS Computer PS480D-BK 480W ATX12V Power Supply
- 4GB RAM (4×1)

Today I got a new processor with new RAM, the new processor is an AMD FX-4350 and RAM is Klevv 8GB (2×4)

I replaced both the processor and the RAM and when I start it up it boots up, but after about 1 – 2 minutes the computer shuts itself down.

I restart it, but the same thing happens. I tried reinstalling Windows but it didn’t complete, a couple of times it would freeze on expanding Windows files and just stay there, otherwise it would get as far as completing Windows setup or the last step of installation, but then it would shutdown automatically and I had to start the installation over again.

I finally installed Windows, reset my BIOS settings to default and tried to change the RAM back to the old stick. Finally, the Windows installation finished but the same thing happened after 1-2 minutes. Can anyone suggest what may be causing this?

Comment: I would suggest that the processor may be overheating. Did you use the same cooler as it had before, and if so, did you use new thermal paste? Without adequate cooling, the machine may be powering itself down to prevent damage to the CPU and other components.

Comment: No I used the heat sink that came with the processor and I believe it did have thermal paste on it

Comment: It'd be worth checking it's seated properly and making good contact. It's unlikely to be the RAM as you've tried the old stick again and still have the same problem, have you tried using the old CPU again?

Comment: No because I don't have any thermal paste for that cpu

Comment: And also I'll check tomorrow to see if the computer is working I turned it off for the night I'll let you know tomorrow thank you

Comment: @AfnanMirza when you say "it did have thermal paste on it" does that mean you took off the cooler and put it back on without putting new thermal paste? As a general rule, you should apply a new application of thermal paste every time you reseat the heatsink

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to boot into an OS installation until after you confirm the new CPU and RAM are working properly. Flaky hardware can corrupt your OS installation making testing accurately pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Boot loop/exit problems are mostly caused by a faulty motherboard, PSU, or RAM. And NO, if your motherboard and RAM were fine yesterday doesn't mean they're fine today as well. Open the cabinet and clean out all the dust, use a blower, don't blow from your mouth, you don't want to "moisturize" the circuitry. Check if all connections are tight enough. Next, follow the steps below, assessing behavior of the computer after each step.

- First of all, you have to use your old CPU for a little bit. Get some cheap thermal paste, it's only a temporary affair.
- Now try using another power supply, not necessarily new, best if it's from a "currently working" system, see if your computer still keeps restarting/shutting down.
- Then try individual sticks of RAM. This will remove bad memory sticks out of the equation. Also, I mostly assume it's not the case, still... RAM for normal consumer-grade computers are non-ECC and unbuffered, and some system's are coded to not allow one or the other to be used, or mix-n-matched. So I hope your Klevv is not ECC/buffered/both(!). Google its specs using the model number.

Now, if your system is still behaving erratically, then it most probably is a faulty motherboard. BTW, you should've updated the BIOS before upgrading the CPU/RAM. Still, see how it goes. Good luck.

Comment: I tried everything you told me other then put the old processor in but when I login this is the error I get Everytime http://imgur.com/29BIGkv

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 14 on the same computer and it works fine i don't know what the hell is happening

Comment: Nvm after like 45+ min it started to do the same thing